# link to download a copy

Tags: hyperlink, download, copy

I have a question  that I have saved an excel file in document of my SharePoint
and given the link of that document in form,

but the problem is whenever user  download and edit that excel same changes get save in my excel file too on SharePoint.

I want user to download a copy on his local machine not to change my file

thank you in advance

Comment: Please help on this

Comment: which version of SharePoint?

Comment: did my answer worked for you? If so mark it as answer so that others can also refer it as answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give only read access to all users on that file. This way user will not able to edit the file.

Answer (score 1):

Add web?=0 in your link...

For example:

```
https://example.com/sites/Lists/Documents/somefile.doc?Web=0
```